# Remove duplicate letters from a string sentence while keeping the spaces from the sentence

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I am trying to take a sentence that a user has entered into a String variable and remove the duplicate letters while keeping the spaces in the sentence. For example if a user enters "hello my name is danny" it will return "Helo my nam is dn".

To do this I have already tried this code:

```
package noRepeats.java;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class NoRepeats {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        System.out.println("Please enter a sentence:");
    
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String userInput = sc.nextLine();
    
        String sentence = userInput;
        
        char[] Array = sentence.toCharArray();
        
        StringBuilder sb3 = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i=0; i<Array.length;i++) {
            boolean repeated = false;
            for(int j = i + 1; j<Array.length;j++) {
                if(Array[i]==Array[j]) {
                     repeated = true;
                     break;
                }
            }
            if(!repeated) {
                sb3.append(Array[i]);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(sb3);
    }
}
```

This code however doesn't keep the spaces of the sentence and it also seems to remove the first letter in a duplicate pair but not the second.

Comment: You could check whether `Array[i]` is different from `" "` before setting `repeated`.

Comment: As an aside, `Array` is a bad name for a variable. It should be `array` (or, even better, something that tells you what it actually is for) since by convention names starting with an uppercase letter are used for class and interface names.

Comment: _"it will return "Helo my nam is dn""_ - That doesn't really match your description , does it? I would have expected "Helo my name is dany"? Or if you meant to remove both of the dupes: "Heo my name is day" OR are you talking about not only adjacently duplicates?

Comment: ^^ If the latter, then I'd first make a histogram of all characters in the sentence (ignoring whitespaces) and then remove all characters with count > 1.

Comment: is `hel o my na   is d    ` the expected output (preserving the length)? or is it `helo my na is d`, keeping only the whitespaces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic you are using to check the `repeated` is slightly incorrect. You need to check if the current character that you are looping is present in the string builder that you have built so far till that point. This way a character will be allowed the first time and not the second time.
For the space thing, it is just a simple condition that you can add.

```java
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if(array[i] == ' ') {
        sb3.append(array[i]);
        continue;
    }
    boolean repeated = sb3.indexOf(String.valueOf(array[i])) >= 0;
    if (!repeated) {
        sb3.append(array[i]);
    }
}
```

Also, I wanted to point that you should not start your variable name with a Capital letter, so the variable `Array` should be `array`.

Comment: Brilliant thanks so much for pointing everything out. I've made all the changes and it's all working as intended. Thank you!